# What is this JSON-like syntax in Flutter's widget constructors?

Tags: syntax, dart, flutter

I'm completely new to Dart and Flutter, and I've been absorbing as much info as possible from docs and tutorials. While Dart itself doesn't trouble me much, Flutter has been difficult so far. For example, I can't seem to wrap my head around this syntax from the Hello World app:

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
    ),
    // ...
  ),
);
```

I can't find syntax like it in Dart docs. Is it a constructor, like `ClassName(prop1:val1, prop2:val2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. `Scafford()` is instantiating a Widget (class) constructor, which you can see defined [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) in the docs.

Flutter UI is a lot of nested constructors like this. Many of the arguments to a Widget's constructor are just, themselves, Widgets.

In your Hello World example the `Scaffold` Widget's `appBar` parameter takes an `AppBar` Widget. The `AppBar` itself has a parameter named `Title` which takes a `Text` Widget.

Comment: The doc you linked uses curly braces like this ```Scaffold({prop:value})```, so I guess the ones shown in the tutorial are syntactic sugars?

Comment: Looks like I linked to the `Scaffold` constructor rather than the Material class, sorry about that. Edited now. This is the link to the Material class: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html

Comment: @starleaf1 Curly braces are used in the function/method *declaration* to define named parameters.  They aren't used at the callsite.

Answer (score 1):

You're observing Dart's [optional named parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters).  It's not Flutter-specific.